# Is there a way to schedule Jenkins jobs to run with different versions of Maven according to a cron rule?

Tags: maven-2, jenkins, maven-3

We are using Maven 2.2.1 and Jenkins. We have some 300-400 modules. A few months ago, we finalized the migration from Ant to Maven and at that time the goal was to make sure things built properly under Maven 2.2.1, as we weren't still willing to move directly to Maven 3.0.x. Yeah, we knew that Maven was relatively stable, but due to the effort required in migrating all of the modules and assemblies (from Ant), we chose to stick with a well-known stable version such as 2.2.1.

In order to make a list of the modules which are not fully compliant with Maven 3.x, I would like to schedule the Jenkins jobs (that currently run them using Maven 2.2.1) to build them using 3.0.4 at a scheduled time during the night. How can I do this?

Thanks in advance!

Martin

Comment: Not that i know. But what gets me confused is why you don't migrated directly to MVN 3.0.X, cause now you are on Tool version which will not be developed any more. Maven 3. will be. Simple solution for your problem is setting up two different jobs one which will use MVN 2.2.1 and one which will use MVN 3.0.X and schedule them to different times.

Comment: Well, at the time we started the migration (which was a lengthy process), Maven was at version 3.0.1 and with such a big change we were only inclined to migrate to a proven working version of Maven. A number of plugins were still rather fragile such as the maven-site-plugin and wanted to avoid having to figure out problems in Maven itself (and not our own projects).

Furthermore, duplicating 300-400 jobs is not really what we're looking for as a solution.

Comment: The site area is one of the changes between mvn 2. and mvn 3 (intended) (maven-site-plugin in particular). But apart from that i don't see an other solution than duplicating the jobs and testing the build. The duplication itself of course can be done by script (groovy?)

Comment: The thing is -- that will double the number of jobs we have, which is not quite what I was looking for.

Comment: If you schedule them to different times it is no problem. Furthermore there existing views in jenkins to handle a large number of jobs. As i mentioned before running different maven versions based on scheduled time is not supported by jenkins. So what do you expect?

Comment: Internally, Jenkins treats Maven 3 builds totally different from Maven 2 builds. So I don't see any chance to switch the Maven version within the same Job configuration. The only thing that comes into my mind is to setup a freestyle project that sets `MAVEN_HOME` based on the current time and executes `$MAVEN_HOME/bin/mvn`. Another option would be to setup a second Jenkins instance that runs the same projects with Maven 3.0.x. The jobs can easily be copied from one instance to another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a screaming hack, but should work. As it is a hack, I am going to leave figuring out the exact details to you ;-)

You need to set up two jobs to fence the maven 3 jobs.

Both jobs will need the [Groovy Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+plugin) in order to add a build step.

You will set up three versions of Maven in the System configuration.

- Maven 2.2.1
- Maven 3.0.4
- Maven 2.2.1 by day 3.0.4 by night

The first job will access the global configuration and change `Maven 2.2.1 by day 3.0.4 by night` to point to the same path as `Maven 3.0.4`. The second job will switch it back.

The code will need to be something like

```
import hudson.tasks.*;
Maven.DescriptorImpl descriptor = jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.getDescriptor(Maven.class);
Maven.MavenInstallation[] installs = descriptor.installations.clone; 
// clone the array because we will be modifying it
Maven.MavenInstallation v3 = null;
for (Maven.MavenInstallation i: installs) {
  if (i.name.equals("Maven 3.0.4")) { v3=i; break;}
}
v3.class; // throw NPE if null (should be non-null)
for (int i = 0; i < installs.length; i++) {
  if (installs[i].name.contains("by night")) { installs[i] = new Maven.MavenInstallation(installs[i].name,v3.home); break;}
}
descriptor.setInstallations(installs);
```

Note I have not checked the above for syntax, but it should be close enough to get you sorted.

The reverse job should be trivially easy

Comment: @stefan-ferstl Note this solution will work even if you are using the Maven project type ;-)